# EFPocoAdapter use

Tags: .net, entity-framework, architecture

after much debating between nhibernate and EF, our team has decided to go for EntityFramework with EFPoocoAdapter to solve the POCO problem with EF.

Wondering if there are projects (> 400 db tables) being developed using this adapter, and if there are things that we should be aware of while using it.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

EF natively supports POCOs in .NET 4.0. If you don't plan to ship in the next month or two, you might consider using that. With all that said, I mostly consider POCOs a lie (my "plain" objects don't have everything declared public virtual, and have the type at runtime which I declared them) and somewhat less than necessary if you are good with LINQ projections. But if you really want them, .NET 4.0 has them.

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you know the release date of .net 4.0 ?

Comment: Well, word on the street is that Windows 7 comes out 22 October 2009. Make what you will of that.